# How to handle difficult processes like calculating average score in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Designing an application with PHP and MySQL which helps teachers to take online multi-choice tests.  Each exam has 100 questions and each question has more than 4 choices.

When more than 1000 users participate in an exam, when the system admin goes to "Stats" to see what's the average score or other stats, after a lot of thinking, the system does not show anything: no result, no stats.

Calculation: 100 questions * 4 choices * 1000 users to get the average score.

When we run the web server on a more powerful PC, it shows the stats, but in a shared server it does not show anything.

Table architecture is InnoDB.

How can I calculate the average score and/or export the results to a CSV file, or adding them to an array and sort them?

here is the code which calculate final score before exporting to csv file:

```
$result_list = array();
foreach($UserTestList as $userTestProp)
{
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]=array();
    ....
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['utid'] = $userTestProp['utid'];
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['utlength'] = gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime($userTestProp['utlast_activity'])-strtotime($userTestProp['utstart_datetime']));
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['utuser_ip'] = $userTestProp['utuser_ip'];
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['utbrowser'] = $userTestProp['utbrowser'];
    ...
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['correct'] = $test->GetNumOfAnswers('correct',$userTestProp['utid']);
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['incorrect'] = $test->GetNumOfAnswers('incorrect',$userTestProp['utid']);
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['none'] = $test->GetNumOfAnswers('none',$userTestProp['utid']);
    $result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['final_score'] = ($testInfo['tminus_mark']==1?round(($result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['correct']-($result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['incorrect']/3)),2):$result_list[$userTestProp['utid']]['correct']);
}
```

and here is GetNumOfAnswers method:

```
function GetNumOfAnswers($type,$utid)
    {
        global $table_prefix;
        $total_correct_answers=$total_incorrect_answers=$total_none_answered=0;
        $QuestionList = $this->GetLessonQuestionListByUTID($utid,NULL);
        foreach ($QuestionList as $QuestionInfo)
        {
            switch ($this->IsCorrect($utid,$QuestionInfo['qid']))
            {
                case '1':
                    $total_correct_answers++;
                    break;
                case '0':
                    $total_incorrect_answers++;
                    break;

                default:
                    $total_none_answered++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        switch ($type) {
            case 'correct':
                return $total_correct_answers;
                break;
            case 'incorrect':
                return $total_incorrect_answers;
                break;
            case 'none':
                return $total_none_answered;
                break;
            case 'all':
                return count($QuestionList);
                break;
        }
    }
```

and here is IsCorrect method:

```
function IsCorrect($utid,$qid)
    {
        global $table_prefix;
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT `qcid` FROM `".$table_prefix."user_test_question` INNER JOIN `".$table_prefix."user_test_question_choice` 
            ON `".$table_prefix."user_test_question`.`utqid`=`".$table_prefix."user_test_question_choice`.`utqid` WHERE `utid`=? AND `qid`=?");
        $values = array($utid,$qid);
        $query->execute($values);
        $qcid_chosen = $query->fetchAll();
        if(empty($qcid_chosen))
            return 2;
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT `qcid` FROM `".$table_prefix."questions` INNER JOIN `".$table_prefix."questions_choices` 
            ON `".$table_prefix."questions`.`qid`=`".$table_prefix."questions_choices`.`qid` WHERE `".$table_prefix."questions`.`qid`=? AND `qcis_answer`=1");
        $values = array($qid);
        $query->execute($values);
        $qcid_correct = $query->fetchAll();

        if ($qcid_chosen==$qcid_correct)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

        return $counts;
    }
```

Comment: That's what databases are designed for. Let's start with having a look at your queries, shall we?

Comment: Do it in your php code and it will do it very quickly.

Comment: Add your php and mysql code so we can help

Comment: Please add tables and queries.

Comment: @TobyAllen Quite the opposite, do it in SQL because it's designed and optimised to do just that.

Comment: I think you would need to proivde more information about the structure of your tables, and the query you are running, there is nothing to go by here so far.

Comment: Getting these figures from a well-structured and properly-indexed database should take less than a few seconds on my 1990 Game Boy. Please show us your tables structures.

Comment: I agree with @MihaiStancu: The average should be calculated in MySQL. You should check your tables: are they properly indexed?

Comment: Try using the AVG(column) function in mysql (a query).  This will be faster and much more memory efficient than pulling down the data and calculating in php.  If you query is complex, share the query code.  With regards the shared environment, is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have some design flaw in your structure/application. MySQL i fairly capable of calculating averages for huge data sets.

Are your data structure conveniently arranged for easiest reading performance?

Are your tables indexed on the columns which are read the most?

Is your application averaging logic run in MySQL as one query? or is it run in PHP?

If it's run in PHP then most likely your shared hosting environment has a PHP memory_limit that you're exceeding (because you're trying to read a lot of data from MySQL into PHP and the process it).